# Adding Emoji List to HTML Element without lag

Tags: javascript, html, list

Is there a way to add an emoji list to an element without lag? I've seen this in many websites but don't know how they did it.

When I want to add an emoji to the list, I create a button with some style and onclick events, and then put the emoji in the button's innerHTML.

The code which needs to be repeated 2260 times:

```
document.getElementById('emojicard').innerHTML += '<button class="w3-button w3-center" style="width: 64px;"'
                    +'onclick="document.getElementById('+"'inputarea'"+').value += this.innerHTML;">' + emojis[emojiIndex]+'</button>';
                    emojiIndex++;
                    document.getElementById('emjprogbari').innerHTML = emojiIndex + ' out of ' + emojis.length;
                    document.getElementById('emjprogbar').style.width = (100*emojiIndex/emojis.length)+'%'
```

I usually have to do it in an updating function, but it creates lag. If I put it somewhere else, the website freezes for a while. (I have 2260 emojis in the list)

I don't want to add all of the emojis in that element manually, because, as I have said, there are 2260 emojis in my list and I will add more to that list. Please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep appending html on the page will cost a big effort to the browser, the better way is appending html to the variable and print it out at the end.

Start by defining a variable:

```
var html = '';
```

Start your loop:

```
html += '<button class="w3-button w3-center" style="width: 64px;"'
                    +'onclick="document.getElementById('+"'inputarea'"+').value += this.innerHTML;">' + emojis[emojiIndex]+'</button>';
                    emojiIndex++;
                    document.getElementById('emjprogbari').innerHTML = emojiIndex + ' out of ' + emojis.length;
                    document.getElementById('emjprogbar').style.width = (100*emojiIndex/emojis.length)+'%'
```

Print out the html:

```
document.getElementById('emojicard').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: is it better than adding it to an element with style 'display:none'?

Comment: Thanks! It's a million times more faster now! You saved my life! 

Comment: Please give the answer a vote up and accept if it helps :)

Comment: I have 11 reputation only :(

Comment: I place the html content in a variable and then return its value also. Look at line 71 to 101 at https://github.com/DigiLive/EmojiPopper/blob/master/src/js/emojiPopper.js of my jQuery plugin.